# Oracle plsql ORA-39726 error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have my plsql block as below:

```
DECLARE
CURSOR cdrimei IS select distinct(table_name) as tname from user_tab_columns 
where column_name = 'CALLED_NUMBER_TIPO_ABONADO' and table_name not like '%_V' order by table_name;
BEGIN
FOR i in cdrimei
LOOP

execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE '||i.tname||' DROP (IMEI_CHAIN ,IMEI_STOLEN)';
execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE '||i.tname||' ADD (IMEI_CHAIN varchar2(255),IMEI_STOLEN varchar2(255))';

END LOOP;
END;
/
```

After executing this I am facing the below error:

```
ORA-39726: unsupported add/drop column operation on compressed tables
```

I don't understand the meaning of compressed tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compressed tables have some limitations documented in the [Administrator's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/tables002.htm#autoId11):

> The following restrictions apply when adding columns to compressed tables:
>
> - Basic compression—You cannot specify a default value for an added column.
> - OLTP compression—If a default value is specified for an added column, then the column must be NOT NULL. Added nullable columns with default values are not supported.
>
> The following restrictions apply when dropping columns in compressed tables:
>
> - Basic compression—Dropping a column is not supported.
> - OLTP compression—DROP COLUMN is supported, but internally the database sets the column UNUSED to avoid long-running decompression and recompression operations.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marco. But is there any way we can add/drop columns because I need to query for some 50 tables.

Comment: The `ADD` statement should work since you are not specifying default values.

Instead of `DROP` you could try `SET UNUSED`.